# Map core data row from one table (entity) to an array of [CLLocation]?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

In my ios app I am using Core data and I need to save in a table an array of "Regions" I will get from JSON.

The model for the "Region" object is quite simple:

```
class Region : NSObject, NSCoding {

...

//MARK: -
//MARK: - Properties

fileprivate var id: String
fileprivate var name: String
fileprivate var boundaryPoints: [CLLocation]
fileprivate var midCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    return getPolygonFromBoundaryPoints().coordinate
}

init(id: String, name: String, boundaryPoints: [CLLocation]) {

    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.boundaryPoints = boundaryPoints

    super.init()
}


//MARK: -
//MARK: - NSCoding

...

//MARK: -
//MARK: - Getters and Setters

...

}
```

The problem is I need to persist this in a table where a record would be something like this:

Regions table:

### id | title | [CLLocation]

What would be the best solution for mapping a row to an array of (lat,lng) points ( in this case [CLLocation]) when storing information about a "Region" object ? as the "Region" object model contains an array of boundary points.

In another words how should I go about saving an object model that has an array property to sql using Core data ? (interested in tables' structure and relationships)

Comment: You will need a related entity to store your CLLocation lattitude and longitude values and use a 1 to many relationship between your region and the locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the value in core data as `Transformable` and use a value transformer. You can find a tutorial with more details here: http://lextech.com/2013/01/core-data-transformable-attributes/

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Are there any performance / overhead issues for this not use this method and to use the method Paulw11 mentioned ? If i would have to store locally thousands of records in the Region entity ? Please advise, I'm a beginner with Core data.

Comment: The relationship solution that Paulw11 is talking about would be easier to debug as you can use a SQLite explorer such as Base (http://menial.co.uk/base/) to view the coordinates outside of the app running, but I'm pretty confident that my solution would be faster as it doesn't have to have another relationship which always has an overhead associated with it. The other problem with Paulw11's solution is that your model would have to have separate longitude and latitude, with the value transformer you can use CLLocation directly. There are pro's and cons to both solutions so it's up to you!